# OpenCSV csvwriter is putting everything in one cell

Tags: export-to-csv, opencsv

I've been trying this for a while, but nothing I try works. Every time I try to write to the CSV file everything just gets put into a single cell.

I've tried CSVWriter, openCSV, SuperCSV and BufferedWriter, but every time everything ends up in one cell.

Ignore the ArrayLists, they have nothing to do with this at the moment.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;


class OutputFile {

public static void outputFile(ArrayList<String> info1, ArrayList<String> info2, ArrayList<Double> info3, 
        ArrayList<Double> info4, ArrayList<String> info5, ArrayList<String> info6, ArrayList<String> info7) throws IOException{

 CSVWriter cs = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("testing.csv"));

 String [] record = "this,is,test,data".split(",");

 cs.writeNext(record);


 cs.close();




    }

}
```

Comment: How you fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the Excel recognises ';' and not ','. After this change everything worked out perfectly.

I hope this answer saves someone all the time I've wasted in the future!

Answer (score -1):

In the constructor use this:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("testing.csv"), ',');
```

And in the record `String` replace `#` for `,`; the `split` will do the rest:

```
String [] record = "this#is#test#data".split(",");
```